# How to systematically count the number of integer isosceles triangles?

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

How to count number of isosceles triangles with integer sides where all are less than $a,a\in\mathbb R$(say 9999). Yes I know the triangle inequality. Let two sides be $x$ and remaining be $y$. Then $2x>y,x+y>x\iff y>0$. I can get individual cases, but what if $a$ is very large as in my example, how to count efficiently/systematically then?

Comment: @user3491648 why not? why can't we count triangles?

Comment: OP wants to count the number of triangles with integer side lengths less than a given real number.

Comment: please don't downvote it unnecessarily.

Comment: @user3491648 you could have asked me once, rather than.....(u-no)

Comment: Is there a reason you want $a$ to be the maximum length of any of the sides instead of the perimeter? For the latter, there might be something interesting to be found [here](http://web.maths.unsw.edu.au/~mikeh/webpapers/paper98.pdf).

Comment: @user3491648 All

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the equal sides can have any length between $1$ and $9999$.

If the equal sides have length $a$, then the other side has length at least $1$ and at most $2a-1$

We count the triangles for each $a$.

When $1\le 2a-1 \le 9999$ the number of triangles is $2a-1$, so the total is a sum from $a=1$ to $a=5000$, which you should be able to compute.

When $2a \gt 10000$ there are just $9999$ triangles, so you can count the number from $a=5001$ to $a=9999$.

Then add them together.

I've answered your question - which is "how to do it" - but left you to fill in the details by following through the method. When you have a formula, probably worth checking it on some small numbers like $5$ or $6$ for the maximum side (one odd and one even because you need to handle the factor $2$ correctly).

Comment: "Note that the equal sides can have any length between 1 and 9999." then it's equilateral

Comment: @ADG Every equilateral triangle is isosceles (it fulfils the criteria for being isosceles). But if you want to eliminate the equilateral ones, there are obviously $9999$ of them and you can deduct them at the end.

Comment: ok, I just meant exclusively isoceles.

Answer (score 1):

Call the side of the triangle whose length differs from the other sides the base. Make the base have integer side length. On the two ends of the base, make circles of integer radius. If the circles have radius at least half the length of the base, they will intersect making an integer isosceles triangle.

So for each $n$ (base length), we want to count the number of integers which are both $\leq 9999$ and $\geq n/2$.

The answer should be quadratic in $n$.

To find the formula, use the formula for $1 + 2 + \dotso + n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$, and split the base length into even and odd cases.

Comment: how does that help count?

Comment: I added a hint.